# DataTables 1.9.4 server side variables

Tags: datatables

I am using DataTables.net to display my main content of an aspx site. I have several buttons that determine the data that should be loaded into the table.

Button 1 sets iFilterBy = '3' whereas Button 2 sets iFilterBy = '2'.

The first time around, click either of these respectively, works fine. However, if I've pressed Button 1 first, and the click button 2 - iFilterBy is still set to the value of button 1, '3' in this case.

Clicking button 2 again, works correctly.

the Table structure is :

```
var getMessageDate = function(button1Orbutton2) {

    oMessageDate = $("#tble").dataTable({
          "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'lT><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
          "aLengthMenu": [
            [5, 25, 50, 100, 250, -1],
            [5, 25, 50, 100, 250, "All"]
          ],
          "iDisplayLength": 5,
          "bSortClasses": true,
          "bPaginate": true,
          "bAutoWidth": false,
          "bProcessing": true,
          "bServerSide": true,
          "bDestroy": true,
          "sAjaxSource": "SOMEPAGE,
        "sScrollY ": "300px ",
        "bScrollCollapse ": true,
        "sPaginationType ": "bootstrap ",
        "bDeferRender ": true,
        "fnServerParams ": function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name ": "iFilterBy ", "value ": button1Orbutton2 });
        },
        " fnRowCallback ": function(nRow, aoData) {

        },

        "fnServerData ": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            $.ajax({
                "dataType ": 'json',
                "contentType ": " application / json; charset = utf - 8 ",
                "type ": "GET ",
                "url ": sSource,
                "data ": aoData,
                "error ":
                    function(xhr) {
                         var contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content - Type ");
                        if (xhr.status === 401 && contentType.toLowerCase().indexOf("
          text / html ") >= 0) {
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    },
                "success ":
                    function(msg) {
                        fnCallback(jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d));
                        $("#tble ").show();
                    }
            });
        },
    });
};
```

I've omitted alot of detail, but the complete code base does work.

The calling buttons are as such:

```
$('#button1').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (oMessageDate.fnGetData().length == 0) {
        getMessageDate("2");
               // Get the data specific just for the numbers.
    } else {

        // Filter what is already there.
        oMessageDate.fnFilter("Some text detected");
    }
});
```

So, my question is why does it take two clicks, after the `iFilterBy` value has been set?

Comment: You could try my yadcf plugin for datatables, see this server side filtering showcase page http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html (just clear Engine / Just a Date columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear where you're getting the values of `button1Orbutton2` from, but if it was a hidden field...

```
$('#button1').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#button1Orbutton2').val('3');
    oMessageDate.fnDraw();
}

$('#button2').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#button1Orbutton2').val('1');
    oMessageDate.fnDraw();
}
```

So what's happening here is that when you click one of the buttons, a filter value is assigned to a hidden field. Then `fnDraw()` to redraw the table, using the `iFilterBy` filtering parameter specified in `fnServerParams`

Comment: Hi MarkpSmith, the val is hardcode. the function call getMessageDate() is then passed the value

Comment: I want to either filter the data that is already there, or create a new data set,

Comment: fnDraw has the same effect. First time I click the button all is fine. click it again, and it's still retains the value previously, click again (same button) and all is well.

Comment: I had my logic incorrect. I was checking if the datatable == 0, well the first click made this not true. Doooh